# Head of table set as sticky, but it moved while scrolling

Tags: html, css

The main problem:

After setting scroll bars to be on top and on left, and setting table head to be sticky, head still moves while scrolling.

A few other issues, but less important:

If there is a better way to set scroll left, than using "direction" CSS property is better, because the site allows to choose the display language, and when choosing a language in which the display is from right to left, because of the current "direction" it is necessary to reverse the CSS.

If it's possible, it is nicer to take out the head of the table from the scroll, but the length of the columns is different and the head should match the columns.

code attachment,

Thanks!

```js
const table_container = document.getElementsByClassName("table_container")[0];


  // Align the horizontal scroll bar to the left
  table_container.scrollLeft = -table_container.scrollWidth;


  // Align the vertical scroll bar to the top
    table_container.scrollTop = table_container.scrollHeight;
```

```css
.table_container {
  height: 150px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
  
  /* Align the horizontal scroll bar to the left */
  direction: rtl;
  
  /* Align the vertical scroll bar to the top */
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.table_content {
  /* Align text after flipping */
  direction: ltr;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

table {
  overflow: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: bisque;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  text-align: start;
  vertical-align: top;
}

thead {
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

td {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="table_container ">
  <table class="table_content">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>aaaaa1</th>
        <th>aaa</th>
        <th>aaa</th>
        <th>aaa</th>
        <th>aaa</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>bbb1</td>
        <td>bbbbbbb</td>
        <td>bbb</td>
        <td>bbb</td>
        <td>bbb</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ccc1</td>
        <td>ccc</td>
        <td>ccccccccc</td>
        <td>ccc</td>
        <td>ccc</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ddd1</td>
        <td>ddd</td>
        <td>ddd</td>
        <td>ddddddddddd</td>
        <td>ddd</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>eee1</td>
        <td>eee</td>
        <td>eee</td>
        <td>eee</td>
        <td>eeeeeeeeeeeeee</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without transform its works ok.

```css
.table_container {
    height: 150px;
    width: 400px;
    direction: ltr;
    overflow: auto;
   
  }
  
  .table_content {
    direction: ltr;
 
  }
  
  table {
    overflow: auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  
  tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
  }
  
  tr:hover {
    background-color: bisque;
  }
  
  th,
  td {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    text-align: start;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  
  th {
    background-color: lightblue;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  td {
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
```

```html
 <div class="table_container ">
        <table class="table_content">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>aaaaa</th>
              <th>aaa</th>
              <th>aaa</th>
              <th>aaa</th>
              <th>aaa</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>bbb</td>
              <td>bbbbbbb</td>
              <td>bbb</td>
              <td>bbb</td>
              <td>bbb</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>ccc</td>
              <td>ccc</td>
              <td>ccccccccc</td>
              <td>ccc</td>
              <td>ccc</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>ddd</td>
              <td>ddd</td>
              <td>ddd</td>
              <td>ddddddddddd</td>
              <td>ddd</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>eee</td>
              <td>eee</td>
              <td>eee</td>
              <td>eee</td>
              <td>eeeeeeeeeeeeee</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Zillur Rahim, but in your solution scrolling down and right, instead of up and left...